# Distribution of stopping times

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I encountered the following question in my research:

Let the diffusion process $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be governed by
$$d X_t=s(1-X_t)X_td B_t$$
where $X_0\in (a,b)\subseteq (0,1)$, $s>0$, and $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. Define the stopping time $\tau\equiv\inf\{t\ge 0\,|\,X_t\notin (a,b)\}$.

My question: Is it true that $\mathbf E[\tau]$ is decreasing in $s$? And also, is it possible to explicitly derive (or at least sharply characterize) the distribution of $\tau$ with $s$ being a parameter? If this is possible, how does $s$ shift the distribution of $\tau$?

Can anyone give me some hints on this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't it be true in general that if $dX_t=f(X_t)dB_t$ and you change $f$ to $g$ s.t. $|g|> |f|$ then $\tau_f$ stochastically dominates $\tau_g$ (hence $E(\tau_f)> E(\tau_g)$)? As you intensify the noise, $X_t$ spreads out more for every $t$ and hence $\tau$ goes down? Given that, you can upper/lower bound $s(1-X_t)X_t$ in terms of $s,a,b$ and reduce to either regular Brownian motion (less precise but well-known first passage times) or geometric Brownian motion (more precise but you can still probably find formula for first-passage times).

Comment: Every such diffusion can be represented as an explicit time change of a standard Brownian motion. Thus, the paths are the same but the processes "walk on them" more or less quickly. Thus the stochastic domination of exit times one can think of indeed holds--and in particular the comparison of moments you are asking about.

Comment: I totally agree with these intuitions. But my problem is that I cannot prove them rigorously (I am not very familiar with literature on stochastic calculus). Would you give me some theoretical references? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, my destination is to show that $\mathbf E_x[e^{-r\tau}]$ is increasing in $s$, which, I think, should be established based on a stochastic dominance argument (otherwise this will be very difficult and probably intractable). I want to show that for every sample path of the Brownian motion, the hitting (if happens) will happen earlier (actually hitting happens almost surely in our case). But I got stuck here: it is true that with the same starting point $x$, |dx| is greater for larger $s$. But $x(1-x)$ may decrease as $x$ increases, so in the next step I am lost.

Comment: @A.S. $\langle$ *Sigh*... $\rangle$ Not at all. Keyword: Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz. (If you actually meant to mention that the quadratic variation might be bounded, add to the pot Problem 4.7 page 175 in section 3.4 of Karatzas and Shreve.)

Comment: @user65018 Please see Section 3.4.B of the reference mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Did I simply haven't encountered/considered stochastic time changes. Retracted. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: It seems that I need to compute the quadratic variation of the stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ as generated in the way given above, which I am not sure how to do. Is it possible to prove that for every realization of the Brownian motion $B_t(\omega)$, the quadratic variation of the corresponding trajectory $X_t(\omega)$ is increasing in $s$? Would you please give me some hint on that? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tau(x)=E(\tau|X_0=x)$. Then $\tau(x)$ is the solution to the following boundary value problem:
$$L\tau=-1\tag 1$$
$$\tau(x)=0 \text{ for } x\in\{a,b\}\tag 2$$
where $$L=\frac 1 2(s(1-x)x)^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$ is the generator of the diffusion. You just need to integrate $(1)$ twice and use $(2)$ to determine constants of integration. You'll get $\tau\propto 1/s^2$- decreasing in $s$ as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the logic of (1). Would you kindly explain that? Many thanks!

Comment: @user Consider starting at $x$ at $t=0$ and advancing by $dt$. Then $\tau(x)=E_x(\tau(X_{dt}))+dt$ which leads to $L\tau=-1$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)).

Comment: But how can we verify that $\tau(\cdot)$ is a suitable function such that the infinitesimal generator is well-defined? Is there a verification approach to check this? Thanks!

Comment: And also, I actually need how $\mathbf E(e^{-r\tau})$ depends on $s$, which is not implied by the fact that $\mathbf E[\tau]$ is decreasing in $s$. For the function $\mathbf E(e^{-r\tau})$, it is difficult to derive the infinitesimal generator. In fact I am interested in making sure whether the change in $s$ will generate stochastic dominance (which is intuitive) on the distribution of $\tau$. Would you give me some hint on that? Many thanks!